# Duvida Subquery MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estou com problema para montar um subquery no MySQL aqui que estou quebrando a cabeça mas não estou conseguindo, se alguém puder me dar uma luz.

Seguinte, tenho uma tabela que tenho duas colunas conforme abaixo e estou precisando pegar o `DISTINCT` do campo descrição e ver o `SUM` do valor de cada descrição

| descricao | valor |
| --- | --- |
| teste | 10 |
| teste2 | 15 |
| teste2 | 20 |
| teste | 30 |
| teste | 40 |

Queria ter uma consulta para ter os valores conforme abaixo.

| descricao | valor |
| --- | --- |
| teste | 80 |
| teste2 | 35 |

Alguém consegue me ajudar ? Tentei fazer um select assim, porém trava o banco de dados

```
SELECT SUM(valor) from tabela where descricao IN (SELECT DISTINCT(descricao) from tabela)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver seria apenas utilizando o [`group by`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html). Sem `subquery`.

Segue a query:

```
SELECT descricao, SUM(valor) FROM <nome_da_sua_tabela> GROUP BY descricao;
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!